# Renamed packages and now activity cannot be found

Tags: android, package

So today I had a bright idea to rename my packages, now my android application which I have schedule for release on thursday is not working.

I am getting a similar error as follows:

```
Error: Activity class {org.me.androidapplication2/com.albertrosa.DEMO.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

I have modified the manifest to reflect the change:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.albertrosa.DEMO"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0"
```

there is more to the manifest but this is all that I have changed. is there something I am missing or doing wrong. I am using netbeans to build this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old topic but someone may find it useful to know when you refactor your package you are required to edit the manifest file but you also need to refactor the generated java files package.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there is a wrong package path here: `org.me.androidapplication2/com.albertrosa.DEMO.MainActivity`

Have you tried to clean the project? Rebuild? Try to search for the old package name, maybe it is hard coded somewhere?!

Comment: well there was that line on the project properties so I changed it to com.albertrosa.DEMO and still same error but with that new package

Comment: I ended up just rebuilding the app. But I am wondering if its 'cuz of the app was on the device with the old name and there was a conflict on the actual device and not in the code itself.

Comment: That can be the reason. I changed my package name, too, not long ago and had some small problems there. I always prefer cleaning/removing/rebuilding/reinstalling everything...

Answer (score 0):

Exactly this just happened to me. Uninstalling the application from the device fixed the problem.